# Android USB Accessory JAR copy to system folders, does it need the odex file too?

Tags: arduino, firmware

I am trying to get my phone to accept USB Accessory mode and run the DemoKit connected to the Arduino [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). My ROM did not contain the appropriate files so, I decided to do it myself.

First the specs

- My phone: [Samsung GT-I9100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II)
- My ROM: 2.6.35.7-I9000XWJVZ (rooted)
- Firmware: 2.3.6

I've succeeded before in copying the .jar .odex and .xml file to the appropriate folders. Although it completely bricked my phone and was stuck in a boot loop. Now, recovered, I want to give it a second try.

What is this .odex file that every other .jar file has in the /system/framework folder?
Do I need to build/copy the .odex file myself (read something that [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) does JIT compiling)?

Is it possible that in my previous attempt, the copying of the .odex (that I got from another phone I9100), bricked mine?

I know I was careless in my previous attempt. Now, I want to approach the subject with a bit more knowledge...